# How to get the Not Exists Record List from the Given List in Presto with ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, presto, dbt

How to get the list of Not Exists Record List from the Given Input Condition?

If we are using Not IN Operator, it will result all the not matching records from the table. But I want to get the not matching record from the Given Input Condition.

[image]

I know this answer is there for oracle database but this is exclusively needed for Presto. Can someone help on this?

```
select i.column_value as country_code     
from table(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL('AU', 'IN', 'ZA', 'DK', 'CH', 'NL')) i   
where not exists 
(select null                                
from country c                              
where c.country_code = i.column_value)
```

Comment: Show us the working Oracle query.

Comment: **Please** don't add vital info into comments - EDIT the question instead.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell This is an example and doesn't contain any vital info as such

Comment: "vital information" in the sense that it b elongs to the question itself. Not lost in these comments. I could not have answered without that query being present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle `SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL` function is used to transform a comma-separated list into a list of rows, just like a select from a table.
An "unnested" array in Presto should substitute for this, e.g.:

```
SELECT t.country_code
FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['AU', 'IN', 'ZA', 'DK', 'CH', 'NL']) AS t(country_code)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM country c
    WHERE c.country_code = t.country_code
)
```